# Unable to connect to my remote Ubuntu system using SSH

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, nat

I want to connect to my remote PC running on Ubuntu 12.10 using SSH. But when I try `ssh my_username@my_current_ip`, I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host 117...** port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have installed `open-ssh` server and manually forwarded the requests at port 22 to the port 22 corresponding to my local IP. Still I cannot connect to the system. I tried nmapping to the system remotely and found port 22 to be closed, but when nmap is run for localhost on the local system, the port is said to be open.

How can I solve this ?

Additional Information: Router: DSL 2520U OS : Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit

Comment: You mean you installed `openssh-server`? Can you explain what you mean by "I manually forwarded the requests at port 22 to the port 22 corresponding to my local IP"?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the **firewall on your router** that is blocking the request.

Have a look at the documentation for your firewall here: ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/DSL-2520U/Description/DSL-2520U_Manual_EN.pdf and specifically the *Firewall* section to configure it to allow connections to the IP of your Ubuntu PC on port 22.